# scala: import functions defined inside implicit class

Tags: scala, implicit

I want to attach static utilities to those classes that extend a trait called Application.

```
trait Application {
    def name: String
}

case class TestApp(name: String) extends Application


object ImplicitConf {
  implicit class AppConfig[T <: Application](val app: T) {

    lazy val conf = loadConfig

    def loadConfig = {
      ConfigFactory.load(app.name)
    }

    def getString(path: String): String = conf.getString(path)
  }
}
```

Now the following works fine:

```
import Application, TestApp
import ImplicitConf._
import AppUtil._

object TestAppConf extends App {

  val app: Application = TestApp("TestAppConf")
  val test = app.getString("hello")
  println(s"The Config value is $test")

}
```

But I am too greedy, how do I covert the call

```
val test = app.getString("hello")
```

Into

```
val test = getString("hello")
```

Comment: You can import all from the app. import app._

Comment: Sorry, the comment is not relevant for implicit

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly convert the app:Application to appWithConfig:AppConfig and import all methods of the appWithConfig:AppConfig

```
   val appWithConfig = new AppConfig(app)
   import appWithConfig._
```

Comment: thanks for responding. As I mentioned in the post, I want to extend my Application trait by attaching static utilities to it by using implicit classes. This is not relevant solution for my specific requirement, especially when I don't want multiple instances of config objects lingering around.

Comment: The following works as well but the compiler doesn't let me omit the this keyword.
 
 object TestAppConf extends App with Application {

   override val name = "TestAppConf"
   val test = this.getString("hello")
   println(s"The Config value is $test")

 }

Answer (score 0):

The best option I had was to reference the methods in the parent object:

```
object ImplicitConf {

  def getString[T <: Application](str: String)(implicit app: T) = AppConfig(app).getString(str)

  implicit class AppConfig[T <: Application](val app: T) {

    @transient lazy val conf = loadConfig


    def loadConfig = {
      ConfigFactory.load(app.name)
    }

    def getString(path: String): String = conf.getString(path)

  }
}
```

Then I was able to invoke as below:

```
object TestAppConf extends App {

  implicit val app: Application = TestApp("TestAppConf")

  val test = getString("hello")

  println(s"The Config value is $test")

}
```